# c#: Show dynamic menu defined in XML from the program

Tags: c#, xml, user-interface, menu, ribbonx

I have Outlook Addin that has buttons defined in XML file. This line is from that file.

```
  <dynamicMenu id="idSaveAttachments" getLabel="GetLabel" image="SaveAttachmentsIcon" size="large" getScreentip="getScreenTooltip" invalidateContentOnDrop="true" getContent="GetAttachmentsMenu" getEnabled="GetEnabled"/>
```

As I understand it defines a button and when it is clicked `GetAttachmentsMenu` function is called that fills the menu. It works perfectly.

Currently I want to show that menu from code. I can call `GetAttachmentsMenu` function and get the content of menu in XML format but I have no idea how to show the menu.

How is it possible? Are there general methods to invoke this kind of XML based UI items from the program?

It is used Ribbon UI model.

I have tried this code:

```
    Outlook.Application applicationObject = Globals.MyThisAddIn.Application;
    Outlook.Explorer  oExp = (Outlook.Explorer)applicationObject.ActiveExplorer();
    oExp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("idSaveAttachments");
```

But I am getting error:

> 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

Answer (score 0):

The Fluent UI doesn't provide anything for that. The `ExecuteMso` method accepts well-known idMso values of built-in controls only.